# Adding a Document Library Template to the noteworthy app list

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have created a document library template. When I go to add apps I will have to search through a list of apps to add the template I have created.

Is there a way to add this document library to "Noteworthy Apps" section?

Answer (score 1):

1. On the home page of the App Catalog site, select the tile labeled either Apps for SharePoint or Apps for Office, depending on which type of app you are using.
2. In the properties dialog form select the Featured check box.